# Conversion of ColdFusion query to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, coldfusion

Can you assist me in converting this coldfusion statement to PHP for updating mysql?

```
<cfquery name="getrecords">
select email,name,id,status from table1
where status = 0
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="getrecords">
    <p>#getrecords.name#</p>
    <p>#getrecords.name#</p>

    <cfquery name="update">
    update table1 set status =1 where status = #getrecords.status#
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: @Matt - It's not obsolete. There have been 2 new major releases in the past year. One by Adobe and one by Railo.

Comment: @MattBusche Fair enough. I guess I exposed my ignorance on that one :-)

Comment: Looks to me like you are looping over a recordset with status=0, and set every record from it with status=1... You could always run ONE query that would display the records with status 0, and then run a SINGLE update statement where status=0. #getrecords.status# is always 0 in your code

Answer (score 1):

Queries don't change within the context of the language that's processing them - they're SQL either way. Read up on executing mysql queries in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

In any programming language, the code you posted is a poor practice because you are running individual update queries inside a loop.  Since you are converting, you should look at improving things.  Here is the same logic, but with only one update query.

```
<cfquery name="getrecords">
    SELECT name
    FROM   table1
    WHERE  status = 0
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="getrecords">
    <p>#name#</p>
</cfoutput>

<cfquery name="updaterecords">
   UPDATE table1
   SET    status = 1
   WHERE  status = 0
</cfquery>
```

Matt already gave you a reference for running mysql queries using php.

Comment: The original query is also vulnerable to sql injection. Whichever language you are using, always protect queries by using bind variables!